# Pendrive capacity decreased after installing ubuntu on it

Tags: usb-drive

My USB capacity is 8 GB . It shows 700 MB 
in disk management. It show 7 GB free space. I am not able to add it.

Comment: Just a guess, but do you know about the difference between gigabyte and gibibyte, as explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/352597/why-do-du-sh-and-the-file-manager-disagree/352621#352621)? Maybe the free space is measured in GiB, not in GB. The USB device's manufacturer probably preferred to sell it as "8 GB" instead of "7,45 GiB" ;)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `I am not able to able to add it`. Do you mean there is 300MB of missing space as they don't add up to 8GB? or do you mean the 7GB space is unusable? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your pen-drive is sold as having 8gb, you won't have access to all of it. The advertised memory is never the actual memory. Some of the space is required for memory allocation.

Also, from what I understand from your question, your pen-drive has 700mb in it and 7gb free? That means you've access to 7.7gb. It's pretty good imo.

Comment: No what i want to say is i used it for making a bootable usb (ubuntu ) and after the installation i formated the pendrive . instead of showing 7 gb it shows 700 mb

Answer (score 0):

Yes no pen drive in the world will have full access to its memory. If it is a 8gb pendrive it will have the full capacity at laboratory level only. So your pendrive is showing its full capacity based on the conditions out side the laboratory. Ans so this is not a problem at all.