# How to make the file manager show file sizes in GiB, MiB, KiB?

Tags: unity, nautilus

It currently shows in GB, MB which are multiples of 10. I'd like it to be multiples of 2.

Comment: I am pretty sure such setting doesn't exist in the default file manager. Might be worth to put a feature requests to the developers

Comment: Related: [Why will Ubuntu no longer measure file size unit as byte, megabyte, gigabyte, etc?](http://askubuntu.com/q/465/37165). P.S.: This quoted title is confusing.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do so, mainly because Ubuntu follows the [Units Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy).

### With base-10

If user expect to see file sizes in base-2 using the default file manager in Ubuntu, forget about it. Most known file managers have been using base-10 for some time already.

File managers that show base-10 a.k.a Metric units (kB, MB, GB):

- Nautilus (GNOME, Unity)^1
- Caja (MATE; Ubuntu MATE)^3
- Thunar (Xfce; Xubuntu)
- Nemo (Cinnamon)^3

### With base-2

While the policy applies to default file manager in Ubuntu for 10.10 and newer releases, there are file managers that did not follow the same.

File managers that show base-2 a.k.a. IEC units (KiB, MiB, GiB):

- Dolphin (KDE; Kubuntu)^2
- PCManFM (LXDE, LXQt; Lubuntu)^3
- Double Commander (cross-platform)

> **Reference notes**
>
> ^1: Nautilus in Ubuntu 10.10+ will now show base-10; previously base-2.
>
> ^2: Dolphin will show either base-2 or base-10 in KDE Plasma 4; otherwise always base-2 in KDE Plasma 5. Some details at below.
>
> ^3: The file manager has an option to show either base-10 or base-2.

Notice that file managers that show file sizes in base-2 are often found as platform independent software. This may be influenced by the fact that operating system for consumers, esp. Microsoft Windows, use [customary binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Operating_systems) a.k.a. JEDEC units.

As for Dolphin file manager, it is the KDE development platform that allows its application programs to show file sizes in base-2, rather than the file manager itself. Such option has been available in KDE Plasma 4, but went missing in KDE Plasma 5.

[image: KDE Plasma 4 has the option to change byte size units]

We can trace back the history, when [the blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-unit-consistency/) was registered in late-2008 by Joel Parker. Two years later, the policy was finally implemented in Ubuntu 10.10. For such carefully planned changes, it is *very less likely* for file manager in Ubuntu to revert the changes. Time will tell.

**TL;DR** Use a file manager that show file sizes in base-2 (KiB, MiB, GiB) for consistent experience across different operating systems. Very less likely for base-2 to be reintroduced in Ubuntu anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I use Thunar 1.8.15 and it has an option to show either base-10 or base-2 (`Edit` → `Preferences` → `Show file size in binary format`). Also see [Xfce wiki](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/preferences).